# MRTK Poke Pointer on different finger

Tags: hololens, mrtk

I am trying to add the PokePointer to a different finger than the index finger. I have tried setting up custom Input Actions and Controller Definitions for that with no success.

How can I attach the PokePointer to a different finger for example the thumb so that I can press buttons with my thumb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SphereCast  and FingerCurosr of PokePointer has been hardcode with Index Tip and does not expose any API to access. It is recommended to [polling the joint pose from the controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/input/hand-tracking?view=mrtkunity-2021-05#polling-joint-pose-from-controller) and raise an event when the location of ThumbTip close to the button.